# How to store a Uint8List in a realm database?

Tags: flutter, dart, realm

The Uint8List could be converted in a `List<Int>` and stored this way in the Realm database, but that means it will take 8x the space.
Is there a better way to store it ?

Comment: Base 64 encode it and store as a string? That will take 33% extra.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a good solution. Way better than storing it as a list of int !

Comment: I'm not familiar with Realm, but if you can guarantee that your database will always be using 64-bit integers and that all clients will use the same endianness (not a problem if the database is local), then you alternatively could store `someUint8List.buffer.asUint64List()`.  However, you would need to: 1. Pad the original `Uint8List` to ensure that its length is a multiple of 8. 2. Separately store the original, unpadded length.  Doing so would add an effectively constant overhead of at most 15 bytes, although implementation would be trickier.

Comment: Really like the question so +1 for that - but... asking for a 'better way' is going to be tricky to answer specifically. Better way in what aspect? If you go with UInt8 your limited to 255 - does that work for your use case or will you be storing a higher number? Then - everything is subjective - we have enormous databases with millions of `Int` value stored and with today's devices, a million `Int`s is a tiny amount of space. Moreover - encoding and decoding those int's takes up overhead itself and *could* affect performance. Just curious.

Comment: @Jay The question implied that 'better' was in regard of the space used. The data comes from a microcontroller where millions of int is definitely not tiny :) This may have skewed my perception, it just feels wrong to take 8 bytes to store each byte of a binary. But you could be right that doing otherwise could be adding more problem than it is solving. Nevertheless, it's always good before making a choice to know what is possible and the cons and pro of every possibilities. The answers really helped in that, yours included.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported (as of June 16, 2023), but there's a PR in progress to add support: https://github.com/realm/realm-dart/pull/1320